# 計算結果をカラムに代入したい

Tags: mysql

例えば
`SELECT genre, STD(point) FROM table GROUP BY genre;`
の結果をgenre_std等に代入したいです。

とりあえず手動で
`UPDATE table SET genre_std = 100 WHERE genre = 1;`
:
:
等としているのですが、効率的なやり方がありそうなので

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サブクエリを使って以下の様に書いてみました。

```
UPDATE
  table t1,
  (
    SELECT genre, STD(point) AS std
    FROM table GROUP BY genre
  ) t2
SET
  t1.genre_std = t2.std
WHERE
  t1.genre = t2.genre
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQLではupdate文にcross joinが使えるので次のように書けます。

```
UPDATE table A,
(SELECT genre, STD(point) point_std FROM table GROUP BY genre) B
set genre_std = point_std
where A.genre = B.genre;
```